# Django Rest Framework: DRYer pagination for custom actions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Suppose I need to set up several GET endpoints that look like this `objects/past`, `objects/future`. Example:

```
@action(detail=False, methods=["GET"], name="Past Objects")
def past(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    startdate = datetime.datetime.now()
    some_user = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username="someuser")

    queryset = self.queryset.filter(
        other__attribute__profile=some_user,
        creation_date__lte=startdate
        ).order_by("-creation_date")

    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)

    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

The above works just fine. But is there anyway to avoid the `page = ... -> serializer= ...` part?

I have specified this in my ModelViewSet:

```
pagination_class = CustomObjectPagination
```

But it seems the pagination is only auto-applied to default methods like **`get_queryset`** and not custom actions. Do I have to write this boilerplate every time I specify a custom action like `past`?

```
page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)

if page is not None:
    serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
    return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Edit:** Should have made it clearer that I'm asking specifically whether there's a built-in way to do the above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think we have any built-in to apply pagination on actions. But, we can have a simple decorator to do this. Make sure that your action returns a list or QuerySet when using this decorator.

```
from functools import wraps
from django.db.models import QuerySet

def paginate(func):

    @wraps(func)
    def inner(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        assert isinstance(queryset, (list, QuerySet)), "apply_pagination expects a List or a QuerySet"

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return inner
```

---

```
@paginate
@action(detail=False, methods=["GET"], name="Past Objects")
def past(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    startdate = datetime.datetime.now()
    some_user = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username="someuser")

    queryset = self.queryset.filter(
        other__attribute__profile=some_user,
        creation_date__lte=startdate
        ).order_by("-creation_date")

    return queryset
```

Comment: Thanks. I did think of decorators or just a simple utility function, I should have made it clearer that I'm asking about a built-in way/method. Useful nevertheless.

Comment: I don't think we have a built-in way. If you look at the implementation for DRF list method, you find the hard way of pagination implementation (Just like you did in your code). I think the above code will serve the purpose. If you want, you can go ahead and combine both `@action` and `@paginate` into a single decorator for ease of use :).

Comment: What a remarkable decorator! You've saved my night.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple function for that:

```
def response_with_paginator(viewset, queryset):
    page = viewset.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = viewset.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return viewset.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    return Response(viewset.get_serializer(queryset, many=True).data)
```

Usage is like:

```
@action(...)
def comments(self, ...):
    queryset = Comment.objects.filter(...)
    return response_with_paginator(self, queryset)
```